# Confusion in a proof related to orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

So to show that $$x \cdot y=\frac{1}{4}[||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2]$$ for all x,y in $ℝ^n$. Does the question simply mean to derive $x \cdot y$ from the right or we think of examples for x and y to get to the right?

Comment: Derive $x\cdot y$ from the right.

Comment: Through a sequence of equivalences work from the right to the left. Note that $\|z\|^2 = z \cdot z$.